# Paypal API after login redirects to blank screen

Tags: php, laravel-5, paypal, paypal-sandbox, sandbox

I have integrated [Laravel Paypal Integration](https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal) and followed all the steps to integrate `express checkout`. When I run the application it shows the following 2 screens:

[image: Test Facilitator - Test Store 1]

After login, I can only see this page and nothing more.

[image: Test Facilitator - Test Store 2]

What could be the problem any guess from anybody?

**Note: This is sandbox**

Comment: did you changed the sandbox client token/access token from default to your sandbox app ?

Comment: @optimus Yes I did

Comment: Does the console scream or cry about anything?

Comment: Did you login as a client into `Paypal` and not as a merchant? Did you check that you've set a `return url` for the paypal to know where to send `token` and `payerID` ?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Are you  re-writing the headers from one domain to another?

Comment: It seems like an issue with the buyer sandbox account. Create a new sandbox US country account (not an India country sandbox account) and try again the payment.

Comment: Have you tried it from incognito tab? I had some weird problems when testing PayPal too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This link may be of some help to you.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/faq/#sandbox-questions) Make sure your sandbox account is for the US, and not India or another country. Another thing to try is making sure your "mode" is set to `live` in [`config/config.php`](https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal#configuration).

```
return [
    'mode' => 'live',        // Can only be 'sandbox' Or 'live'. If empty or invalid, 'live' will be used.
    'sandbox' => [
        'username' => '',       // Api Username
        'password' => '',       // Api Password
        'secret' => '',         // This refers to api signature
        'certificate' => '',    // Link to paypals cert file, storage_path('cert_key_pem.txt')
    ],
    // etc...
];
```

Answer (score 1):

**In the config file:**

*PATH: /config/config.php: ([laravel-paypal](https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal/blob/master/config/config.php))*

**Change 'sandbox' to 'live'**

'mode'    => 'sandbox', // Can only be 'sandbox' Or 'live'. If empty or invalid, 'live' will be used.